# Create Dynamic Form Elements Based on MySQL Data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Assuming I have this MySQL table named `table`

```
id    color    mineral
1     green    emerald
2     red      jasper
3     yellow   beryl
```

I want to create a form that will have something like:

```
Minerals
========
Emerald
Color: Green

Jasper
Color: Red

. . .
```

How do I create this dynamic form? Especially as one cannot exactly predict how long that list can actually be?

Comment: Please specify the technology of your form. ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms?

Comment: @Steve WinForms. Let me include that in the tags.

Comment: Probably a DataGridView is the best approach if you don't know the upper limit of rows in your table.

Comment: @Steve How about if I want buttons added to every database row that  meets the SELECT condition? Buttons in the form I mean.